# footer will not go across in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, footer

I have coded this just in html and works perfect, 
http://akaleez.co.uk/Templates/3/

I then try to make it a wordpress theme and now my footer will not go full across the screen

http://lisas-nails.co.uk/?theme=twentytwelve1

only the bottom black part does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the root of the problem you're facing is actually a matter of certain elements expanding the page scroll horizontally to be wider than the visible content. First, to identify the offending elements:

One of them is `#sidebar`. I'm not actually sure where this came from in your WordPress variant, because it's not present in the original HTML you coded. Anyways, the problem is that this element contains a `<ul>` which is styled to be 600px wide, resulting in the additional horizontal scroll. If you have no need for this element, just delete it, because it doesn't look like you're using it for anything. Or, just remove the `width:600px` on the `<ul>` element, because that's the root of the problem.

The other problem element is the `.left` element, which adds together its `width:100%` and `padding-left:190px` to extend 190px off the viewport. I can't say for sure why this behaviour doesn't occur in your original HTML/CSS - it's possible that there's CSS other than what you originally wrote at play here, since the two pages aren't identical.

To fix this, you can instead rely on the default behaviour of a `<div>`, which extends to cover the entire width of its parent, rather than using `width:100%`:

```
.left {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 190px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

(Above, I essentially just removed the float and changed width to auto.)

The reason why most your footer isn't expanding into the additional space on the right is because it takes a width of 100% - that is, 100% of its parent, which in this case is only as wide as the viewport. But this isn't a new problem, if you make your screen smaller in the original page, you'll see that the footer similarly will not extend into space off of the viewport.

Anyways, I hope this is what you were looking for! If it isn't, or you find parts unclear, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: It did work then i removed the sidebar from page and index and made the footer back to normal

Comment: Great! Glad I could help out. Oh and...ah, if this did solve your problem, could you mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!